# Redux app error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have such error:

> index.js:8 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in
>   JSON at position 0

index.js(action):

```
import { days } from "../components/app";
export function fetchData (day) {
    return async (dispatch) => {dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_START', day });
    const response = await fetch(`....`); 
    const data = (await response.json()).body; 
    dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_END', data });
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_SHIFT', data }); 
    } 
}
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you want?

Comment: it seems that the JSON you received is not correctly formated. Can you provide some exemples ?

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar  i want to figure out how to fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the JSON file behind that hyperlink is valid, I suspect that you have a network error and are receiving a standard HTML error page instead, which starts with `<html>`. That has been the cause of getting the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` error in 99% of the cases I have debugged.

So double check in the console if you are actually receiving this file with the correct type as the response.

EDIT:

You have two issues:

1) the API expects you to fetch the JSON file using HTTPS.
So just add that in front of your url in the actions:

```
import { days } from "../components/app";
export function fetchData(day) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START", day });
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/${day}`);
    const data = (await response.json()).body;
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", data });
    dispatch({ type: "SET_SHIFT", data });
  };
}
```

2) Your `{day}` parameter you need for the URL is not being passed correctly. So there's an issue with how you pass the props or state or something between react and redux. Unfortunately I cannot say what the exact solution for that is, since I don't use react+redux together. But when I replace `{day}` with one of the day strings you provide `export const days = ["23-08-2019", "24-08-2019", "25-08-2019"];`, then the API returns the correct JSON file.

So fix the `HTTPS` issue and then try fixing the `{day}` issue. Then the JSON should come back correctly. You'll still have errors concerning filtering, but that has nothing to do with the problem of the json file and can be solved separately.

Comment: can you see where there may be a bug in my sandbox? and how to fix it?
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-m4lcs

Comment: You can see the errors as well by just clicking the console tab inside your sandbox. You ahve a file that resolves with `undefined` and return a HTML test page instead of the JSON you are looking for. Trying to find the place in the code.

Comment: Can you help me at least a little bit? I'm just a newbie to redux and have been struggling with my application for a whole week.....this is how the application works on a pure reaсt: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-shape-0fkqk

Comment: 1) You need to add `HTTPS://` in front of the url: `await fetch(`https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/${day}`);`, since if I try to query that API, I get an error that it has to be over https. 2) Your day is undefined, so the API returns that HTML template due to the sandbox instead of an error.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Add the `https` and try to find why your `day` is not sent correctly to `fetchData()`.

Comment: I have new problem http://i.piccy.info/i9/cf9eb4b4d4a147505c8e3a903a1ca490/1573222302/61119/1346608/Screenshot_7.jpg

Comment: The JSON problem is solved? Good. Please provide a stringified version of `data`.

Comment: "a stringified version of data" - not understood

Comment: Your screenshot gives an error when you access `action.data`. I cannot know in ANY way what `action.data` is without knowing which code you used. So please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(action))` at the top of the action so we can see what is inside data. Are you using Jose's `.text()` instead of `.json()` by any chance to 'solve' the previous issue?

Comment: do I write for you a link to the corrected sandbox or a link to the API?

Comment: Update your sandbox and repost the link. Guess that will be easiest. Technically you should make this a different question, since your JSON problem should be fixed.

Comment: Update sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-m4lcs

Comment: I understand. So do I have a new question? or will you answer me in this question?

Comment: As I have written in the comment, Jose's answers aren't actually solutions. You are causing this new issue yourself by using `.text()` instead of `.json()`, so you can no longer use data as an array. I'm still digging through the code to find the actual solution to your day problem, which will not break other code.

Comment: Okay, then I'll wait

Comment: We need to find why your buttons do not have the correct date key. When you press a button with a date on it, that date does not get sent correctly to the action. So then the URL becomes invalid. So then you get the HTML error page instead of the JSON response from the API. Try finding that, since my react knowledge is as bad as yours.

Comment: thanks, then i will create another question regarding this error, maybe someone will suggest how to solve this problem

Comment: This fixed the button problem by changing the butons in app.js: `onClick={e => onFetchData(e.target.innerText)}` and then applying my solution for the url problem inside `actions/index.js`. There's probably a proper react way to do this as well. Your new problem is that the APi return an object. Your JSON has two properties: `arrival` and `departure`, which are arrays. So your fiolter code should be either `Object.keys(action.data.arrival)[0]` or `Object.keys(action.data.departure)[0]`.

Comment: Hmm, my link referred to the original, and now I can't find it again. Try using that button event inside what used to be app.js, but that file is changed now. :x Then look at the data and update your `.filter()` code to how the json is structured.

Comment: maybe you try again to write what you wrote in the sandbox? for with my level I will not do it, it will be a pity for your vain labor

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-2oi6y  Fetching the JSOn works now, but it's not clear to me what you want to do with the arrival and departure data. So I'll leave updating the filter functions to you.

Comment: ugh how does this code sandbox even work, it's terribly user unfriendly imho. Every time I close my browser, the code reset back to before my adjustments. Did you see all the changes this time? Or how do I save my changes? Since clicking the link no longer works AGAIN. You have to edit the actions.js and the app.js Anyways, I have to run now, have a great weekend. I'll check this topic again on tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means that what you are trying to JSON parse is not an object. Maybe the response is wrapped in an array, like

```js
[{
   "name": "json"
}]
```

If so, you will get that error.

Comment: Try to `console.log(response.text()).body()` or just `console.log(response).body()` to verify what exactly is the request returning and in which format.

Comment: can you see where there may be a bug in my sandbox? and how to fix it?
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-m4lcs

Comment: Sure thing, just one sec

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I edited your Code Sandbox file `Actions > index.js` to this:

```js
import { days } from "../components/app";
export function fetchData(day) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START", day });
    const response = await fetch(`api.iev.aero/api/flights/${day}`);
    const data = (await response.text()).body;
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", data });
    dispatch({ type: "SET_SHIFT", data });
  };
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!) but now I have new error:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/dad4d9a4c64583950a21cdeff752a696/1573221550/35428/1334636/Screenshot_4.jpg can you suggest something?

Comment: So that means that response.text() is not the way to do it. Try to log into the console this `const data = (await response).body;` then `console.log(data)`

Comment: I have new problem: http://i.piccy.info/i9/cf9eb4b4d4a147505c8e3a903a1ca490/1573222302/61119/1346608/Screenshot_7.jpg

Comment: Using `.text()` will give you just the raw text without parsing it. So I would add that you now explicitly have to use `const parsed = JSON.parse(data);` or nest it inside `const data =`, else you won't be able to acces the data and `.body` will throw a new error. The API problem is the URL, not the way it's parsed, since a valid url: `https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/2019-11-08` will return the correct JSON file, so you can use `.json()`.